# jquery ajax stores %20 instead of spaces

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I have jquery ajax function in my codeigniter view that stores a textfiled value into a field in a Mysql database table. The problem is that it stores the white spaces in the data in the form of %20.
Actually I am not even sure if the problem is with the ajax function or what is going on back there.

Jquery:

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/it_inventory/saveNewAssetType/" + asset_name;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function()
        {   
          alert("New asset saved!");
        }

    });
```

Controller Function:

```
function saveNewAssetType($asset_name="") {
        return($this->it_inventory_model->saveNewAssetType($asset_name))?TRUE:FALSE;
}
```

Model Function:

```
function saveNewAssetType($asset_name){
            $asset_data = array ('code'=>'','name'=>$asset_name);
            return($this->db->insert('asset_types',$asset_data))?TRUE:FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rawurldecode() before you insert into the table,

```
$asset_name = rawurldecode($asset_name);
```